# Write a complicated curl request's R equivalent

Tags: r, curl, httr, rcurl

I have a curl request:

```
curl -k --insecure -X POST https://somehttp -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -d 'grant_type=password&client_id=my_id&username=admin&password=admin&client_secret=k6897pyy-1h7l-11q0-lp10-s20sg4erlq44' | jq .access_token
```

How could i write that request in R. I've seen examples of simple ones, but not this complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously I can't test this with the example you provided, but this should get you close. First ensure you populate these variables correctly:

```r
url       <- "http://www.somehttp.com"
my_id     <- "my_id"
username  <- "admin"
password  <- "admin"
my_secret <- "k6897pyy-1h7l-11q0-lp10-s20sg4erlq4"
```

Now the following code prepares the request, sends it, and parses the response (I'm assuming it is json)

```
library(httr)

H <- add_headers(`Content-Type`= "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                  `cache-control` = "no-cache")

form_body <- list(grant_type    = "password", 
                  client_id     = my_id,
                  username      = username, 
                  password      = password,
                  client_secret = my_secret)

res <- POST(url = url, body = form_body, encode = "form", H)

content(res, "parsed")
```

Comment: What does the cache-control header option do?

Comment: @JoeErinjeri The various uses for this header option can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control